# jQuery autocomplete not able to fetch data with php

Tags: php, jquery

Here I'm implementing a shopping application. Using autocomplete for searching a product is not working. Here is the whole code.

**index.php**

```
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="search.php">
                    <div class="input-group" style="width: 650px;padding-left:150px; ">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Product Here..." name="search_text" id="search">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </form>
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#search').autocomplete({
                    source : 'search_text.php',
                    minLength : 1,
                    autoFocus : true

                });
            });
</script>
```

For fetching data from database
**search_text.php**

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

if (isset($_GET['search_text'])) {

    $sql = "select * from product where product_name like  '%$_GET[search_text]%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $array = array();
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $array[] = array( 'label' => $row['product_name'] , 'value' => $row['product_id'] );
        }
        echo json_encode ($array);
    }
}

?>
```

Can anyone help me to find why it is not working?

Comment: What part of it isn't working? Is it getting as far as the search_text.php script?

Comment: Script is working properly. The problem is with autocomplete that I'm not able to figure out.

Comment: In that case we would need an example replicating your issue via a link or js fiddle